# I have scanned a bunch of receipts and I want to scan/OCR their data into an excel file. How would I do this?

Tags: microsoft-excel, ocr

All the receipts have the same layout (i.e. their order list, transaction dates). I was wondering if my OCR program (Omnipage 17) could go to a certain co-ordinate and recognize the data, then some how produce a csv, or even better an excel file?

Anyone have ideas on how to get these done? I have about 900 receipts (don't ask how I scanned them :D) and I want a quick method on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Mac: http://www.neatco.com/products/neatworks-for-mac
I don't know if you can get the Windows version without also buying a scanner.  There was a company similar to this who seemed to lean more towards the Windows side, but I haven't been able to find/remember them.

Comment: Yes, they have a windows version:  http://www.neatco.com/products.  Unfortunately, on the Windows version, you can't buy the software by itself.  You have to buy one of their scanners with it.  Stupid policy.

Comment: Yes.  "I don't know if you can get the Windows version without also buying a scanner."  :-)